I can't get bootstrap icons to center vertically next to text
I can't get bootstrap star icons to center next to review text in a website I am designing. I imbedded the svgs in my code. I am using some bootstrap 4 classes here as well for context. Here's how it looks right now:
Appearance of review star icons and text:

My code:


.reviews {
        color: black;
}

.review-name {
        font-weight: 700;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
        margin-top: 40px;
}

.review-location {
        font-weight: 400;
}

.stars-container {
        vertical-align: center;
}

.stars {}

.review-date {
        font-weight: 400;
}

.review-content {
        font-size: .9rem;
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<section id="reviews" class="reviews container-md">
            <div class="review-item">
                <p class="review-name">Brian C.</p>
                <p class="review-location">REVIEW LOCATION</p>
                <p class="review-date">
                    <span class="stars"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16"
                            fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-star-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path
                                d="M3.612 15.443c-.386.198-.824-.149-.746-.592l.83-4.73L.173 6.765c-.329-.314-.158-.888.283-.95l4.898-.696L7.538.792c.197-.39.73-.39.927 0l2.184 4.327 4.898.696c.441.062.612.636.282.95l-3.522 3.356.83 4.73c.078.443-.36.79-.746.592L8 13.187l-4.389 2.256z" />
                        </svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                            class="bi bi-star-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path
                                d="M3.612 15.443c-.386.198-.824-.149-.746-.592l.83-4.73L.173 6.765c-.329-.314-.158-.888.283-.95l4.898-.696L7.538.792c.197-.39.73-.39.927 0l2.184 4.327 4.898.696c.441.062.612.636.282.95l-3.522 3.356.83 4.73c.078.443-.36.79-.746.592L8 13.187l-4.389 2.256z" />
                        </svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                            class="bi bi-star-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path
                                d="M3.612 15.443c-.386.198-.824-.149-.746-.592l.83-4.73L.173 6.765c-.329-.314-.158-.888.283-.95l4.898-.696L7.538.792c.197-.39.73-.39.927 0l2.184 4.327 4.898.696c.441.062.612.636.282.95l-3.522 3.356.83 4.73c.078.443-.36.79-.746.592L8 13.187l-4.389 2.256z" />
                        </svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                            class="bi bi-star-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path
                                d="M3.612 15.443c-.386.198-.824-.149-.746-.592l.83-4.73L.173 6.765c-.329-.314-.158-.888.283-.95l4.898-.696L7.538.792c.197-.39.73-.39.927 0l2.184 4.327 4.898.696c.441.062.612.636.282.95l-3.522 3.356.83 4.73c.078.443-.36.79-.746.592L8 13.187l-4.389 2.256z" />
                        </svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                            class="bi bi-star-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path
                                d="M3.612 15.443c-.386.198-.824-.149-.746-.592l.83-4.73L.173 6.765c-.329-.314-.158-.888.283-.95l4.898-.696L7.538.792c.197-.39.73-.39.927 0l2.184 4.327 4.898.696c.441.062.612.636.282.95l-3.522 3.356.83 4.73c.078.443-.36.79-.746.592L8 13.187l-4.389 2.256z" />
                        </svg></span> Jul 10, 2019
                </p>
                <p class="review-content">REVIEW TEXT</p>
                <p class="blockquote-footer">Yelp</p>
            </div>
</section>            



I tried using the vertical-align property to no avail. It made no real difference in the stars-container class. Using vertical-align with the stars class (the span enclosing the svgs) made no difference either, so I didn't even include it:
.stars {      vertical-align: center; }
After reading about this problem I tried the mx-auto (in my case, my-auto) bootstrap class suggested by another poster, but it didn't work for me. Not sure what else to try.

This isn't a typical Bootstrap problem, but more a general HTML/CSS problem, so I added Bootstrap 5.3 to your code, instead of the old Bootstrap 4, when turning your code into a snippet. The outcome is the same.

You were on the right track with vertical-align, but sticking to just keyword values can be frustrating. You need to apply it to both the stars and the text and even then it might not look like you want. I usually just use a pixel correction. Something like: .stars { vertical-align: 3px; }.

Try svg{margin-bottom:.2em}. Also as a debugging method you can add an outline or a background to the svg elements. Additionally: in svg you can reuse the code for the star with  Please read about the  element in SVG. This would simplify your code.

add display: flex;     align-items: center;  to .review-date block, and display: flex; to .stars

I tried .stars { vertical-align: 2px; } first and it worked immediately. I didn't know that property could take numerical values! Great Suggestion.

We are glad that we could help you. You may consider marking one of the answers as the chosen one. It would  really help one of us out.

Use Flex. No custom CSS. If you use Bootstrap, use the helper classes provided by the framework. You only need 2 here : d-flex and align-items-center and some padding / margins if needed.
See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/flex/
Here are 2 snippets with the icon font and with the SVGs. Note that the HTML used around the elements is exactly the same and the display is exactly the same too.
First version with icon font :


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css">

<div class="d-flex align-items-center p-3">
  <i class="bi bi-star-fill"></i>
  <i class="bi bi-star-fill"></i>
  <i class="bi bi-star-fill"></i>
  <i class="bi bi-star-fill"></i>
  <i class="bi bi-star-fill"></i>
  <span class="ms-2">Jul 10, 2019</span>
</div>



Second version with SVG :


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-flex align-items-center p-3">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-star-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
<path d="M3.612 15.443c-.386.198-.824-.149-.746-.592l.83-4.73L.173 6.765c-.329-.314-.158-.888.283-.95l4.898-.696L7.538.792c.197-.39.73-.39.927 0l2.184 4.327 4.898.696c.441.062.612.636.282.95l-3.522 3.356.83 4.73c.078.443-.36.79-.746.592L8 13.187l-4.389 2.256z" /></svg>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-star-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
<path d="M3.612 15.443c-.386.198-.824-.149-.746-.592l.83-4.73L.173 6.765c-.329-.314-.158-.888.283-.95l4.898-.696L7.538.792c.197-.39.73-.39.927 0l2.184 4.327 4.898.696c.441.062.612.636.282.95l-3.522 3.356.83 4.73c.078.443-.36.79-.746.592L8 13.187l-4.389 2.256z" /></svg>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-star-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
<path d="M3.612 15.443c-.386.198-.824-.149-.746-.592l.83-4.73L.173 6.765c-.329-.314-.158-.888.283-.95l4.898-.696L7.538.792c.197-.39.73-.39.927 0l2.184 4.327 4.898.696c.441.062.612.636.282.95l-3.522 3.356.83 4.73c.078.443-.36.79-.746.592L8 13.187l-4.389 2.256z" /></svg>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-star-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
<path d="M3.612 15.443c-.386.198-.824-.149-.746-.592l.83-4.73L.173 6.765c-.329-.314-.158-.888.283-.95l4.898-.696L7.538.792c.197-.39.73-.39.927 0l2.184 4.327 4.898.696c.441.062.612.636.282.95l-3.522 3.356.83 4.73c.078.443-.36.79-.746.592L8 13.187l-4.389 2.256z" /></svg>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-star-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
<path d="M3.612 15.443c-.386.198-.824-.149-.746-.592l.83-4.73L.173 6.765c-.329-.314-.158-.888.283-.95l4.898-.696L7.538.792c.197-.39.73-.39.927 0l2.184 4.327 4.898.696c.441.062.612.636.282.95l-3.522 3.356.83 4.73c.078.443-.36.79-.746.592L8 13.187l-4.389 2.256z" /></svg>
  <span class="ms-2">Jul 10, 2019</span>
</div>




Wrap the star rating in a native JavaScript Web Component <star-rating
Encapsulating HTML, CSS and JS
With shadowDOM you won't have to worry about any other CSS in the page.
Then HTML:
<star-rating rate="3" total="5" date="Jan 1, 1970"></star-rating>
<star-rating total="5" date="Dec 31, 1999"></star-rating>
<star-rating rate="7" total="10" date="Jul 10, 2019"></star-rating>

Outputs:

I simplified that SVG star with: https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/#


<style>
  star-rating {
    --star1size: 20px;
    background:pink;
    margin: 2px;
  }
</style>

<star-rating rate="3" total="5" date="Jan 1, 1970"></star-rating>
<star-rating total="5" date="Dec 31, 1999"></star-rating>
<star-rating rate="7" total="10" date="Jul 10, 2019"></star-rating>

<script>
  customElements.define(
    "star-rating",
    class extends HTMLElement {
      connectedCallback() {
        const star = `<svg fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 160 160">
  <path d="m36 154c-4 2-8-1-7-6l8-47-35-33c-3-3-2-9 3-9l49-7 21-44c2-4 7-4 9 0l22 43 49 7c4 1 6 6 3 9l-35 34 8 47c1 4-4 8-7 6l-44-22-44 23z"/></svg>`;
        const total = this.getAttribute("total") || 5;
        const rate = this.getAttribute("rate") || 0;
        const date = this.getAttribute("date") || "";
        this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" }).innerHTML = `<style>`+
            `:host{display:inline-flex;align-items:center;padding:10px;border-radius:8px}`+
            `svg{color:grey;width:var(--starsize,40px)}`+
            `svg:nth-child(-n+${rate}){color:goldenrod}`+
            `span{margin-left:.5em;font:2em Arial}`+
            `div{display:flex;align-items:center}`+
          `</style><div>${star.repeat(total)}<span>${date}</span></div>`;
      }
    }
  );
</script>




Add this CSS:
.stars {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}

vertical-align takes  care of the alignment, but it only works for block and inline-block elements, therefore the display setting.


.reviews {
        color: black;
}

.review-name {
        font-weight: 700;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
        margin-top: 40px;
}

.review-location {
        font-weight: 400;
}

.stars-container {
        vertical-align: center;
}

.stars {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}

.review-date {
        font-weight: 400;
}

.review-content {
        font-size: .9rem;
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<section id="reviews" class="reviews container-md">
            <div class="review-item">
                <p class="review-name">Brian C.</p>
                <p class="review-location">REVIEW LOCATION</p>
                <p class="review-date">
                    <span class="stars"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16"
                            fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-star-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path
                                d="M3.612 15.443c-.386.198-.824-.149-.746-.592l.83-4.73L.173 6.765c-.329-.314-.158-.888.283-.95l4.898-.696L7.538.792c.197-.39.73-.39.927 0l2.184 4.327 4.898.696c.441.062.612.636.282.95l-3.522 3.356.83 4.73c.078.443-.36.79-.746.592L8 13.187l-4.389 2.256z" />
                        </svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                            class="bi bi-star-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path
                                d="M3.612 15.443c-.386.198-.824-.149-.746-.592l.83-4.73L.173 6.765c-.329-.314-.158-.888.283-.95l4.898-.696L7.538.792c.197-.39.73-.39.927 0l2.184 4.327 4.898.696c.441.062.612.636.282.95l-3.522 3.356.83 4.73c.078.443-.36.79-.746.592L8 13.187l-4.389 2.256z" />
                        </svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                            class="bi bi-star-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path
                                d="M3.612 15.443c-.386.198-.824-.149-.746-.592l.83-4.73L.173 6.765c-.329-.314-.158-.888.283-.95l4.898-.696L7.538.792c.197-.39.73-.39.927 0l2.184 4.327 4.898.696c.441.062.612.636.282.95l-3.522 3.356.83 4.73c.078.443-.36.79-.746.592L8 13.187l-4.389 2.256z" />
                        </svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                            class="bi bi-star-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path
                                d="M3.612 15.443c-.386.198-.824-.149-.746-.592l.83-4.73L.173 6.765c-.329-.314-.158-.888.283-.95l4.898-.696L7.538.792c.197-.39.73-.39.927 0l2.184 4.327 4.898.696c.441.062.612.636.282.95l-3.522 3.356.83 4.73c.078.443-.36.79-.746.592L8 13.187l-4.389 2.256z" />
                        </svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                            class="bi bi-star-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path
                                d="M3.612 15.443c-.386.198-.824-.149-.746-.592l.83-4.73L.173 6.765c-.329-.314-.158-.888.283-.95l4.898-.696L7.538.792c.197-.39.73-.39.927 0l2.184 4.327 4.898.696c.441.062.612.636.282.95l-3.522 3.356.83 4.73c.078.443-.36.79-.746.592L8 13.187l-4.389 2.256z" />
                        </svg></span> Jul 10, 2019
                </p>
                <p class="review-content">REVIEW TEXT</p>
                <p class="blockquote-footer">Yelp</p>
            </div>
</section>




There's not much difference in the appearance between OP's snippet and yours.

@iorgu Well, I suggest you take another close look. In my snippet, the stars are aligned to the baseline of the text, in the OP's snippet they are clearly below that, by about 2 to 3 millimeters. Just try adding the settings yourself and switch it on and off, then you see it in comparison.

I knew that difference, but vertical-align: 2px; would be the center/middle better than the text-bottom value.

@iorgu Concerning your suggestion about vertical-align: 2px;: px is an absolute unit – if there is a different font-size in that element, you'd have to adjust the px value, whereas text-bottomis always text-bottom...

Yes, I know,  the "tweaked to ones need" was referemce to that fact, even though I wrote "based on the vertical-align"". I should've written "based on the font size". And  there might be a solution for that issue with a calc along with var, dynamically...

Just add the following to you CSS stylesheet, and it will work.
.stars,
.review-date {
  display: flex; 
  align-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap; 
  padding-right: 5px; 
}


Display: flex is needed for the alignment features of flex to work.
Align-content: center; centers the content.
Flex-wrap: wrap is needed for the align-content: center to work.
Padding-right: 5px; is for a 5px distance between the .stars and the .review-date.

For more information on flex, you can visit this site: https://demo.agektmr.com/flexbox/
The code in action:


.reviews {
  color: black;
}

.review-name {
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.review-location {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.stars-container {
  vertical-align: center;
}

.review-date {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.review-content {
  font-size: .9rem;
}
/*new code from here*/
.stars,
.review-date {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center; /*this centers the content*/
  flex-wrap: wrap; /*this is needed for the align-content: center to work*/
  padding-right: 5px; /*to put a 5px distance between the stars and the date*/
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<section id="reviews" class="reviews container-md">
  <div class="review-item">
    <p class="review-name">Brian C.</p>
    <p class="review-location">REVIEW LOCATION</p>
    <p class="review-date">
      <span class="stars"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16"
                            fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-star-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path
                                d="M3.612 15.443c-.386.198-.824-.149-.746-.592l.83-4.73L.173 6.765c-.329-.314-.158-.888.283-.95l4.898-.696L7.538.792c.197-.39.73-.39.927 0l2.184 4.327 4.898.696c.441.062.612.636.282.95l-3.522 3.356.83 4.73c.078.443-.36.79-.746.592L8 13.187l-4.389 2.256z" />
                        </svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                            class="bi bi-star-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path
                                d="M3.612 15.443c-.386.198-.824-.149-.746-.592l.83-4.73L.173 6.765c-.329-.314-.158-.888.283-.95l4.898-.696L7.538.792c.197-.39.73-.39.927 0l2.184 4.327 4.898.696c.441.062.612.636.282.95l-3.522 3.356.83 4.73c.078.443-.36.79-.746.592L8 13.187l-4.389 2.256z" />
                        </svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                            class="bi bi-star-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path
                                d="M3.612 15.443c-.386.198-.824-.149-.746-.592l.83-4.73L.173 6.765c-.329-.314-.158-.888.283-.95l4.898-.696L7.538.792c.197-.39.73-.39.927 0l2.184 4.327 4.898.696c.441.062.612.636.282.95l-3.522 3.356.83 4.73c.078.443-.36.79-.746.592L8 13.187l-4.389 2.256z" />
                        </svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                            class="bi bi-star-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path
                                d="M3.612 15.443c-.386.198-.824-.149-.746-.592l.83-4.73L.173 6.765c-.329-.314-.158-.888.283-.95l4.898-.696L7.538.792c.197-.39.73-.39.927 0l2.184 4.327 4.898.696c.441.062.612.636.282.95l-3.522 3.356.83 4.73c.078.443-.36.79-.746.592L8 13.187l-4.389 2.256z" />
                        </svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                            class="bi bi-star-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path
                                d="M3.612 15.443c-.386.198-.824-.149-.746-.592l.83-4.73L.173 6.765c-.329-.314-.158-.888.283-.95l4.898-.696L7.538.792c.197-.39.73-.39.927 0l2.184 4.327 4.898.696c.441.062.612.636.282.95l-3.522 3.356.83 4.73c.078.443-.36.79-.746.592L8 13.187l-4.389 2.256z" />
                        </svg></span> Jul 10, 2019
    </p>
    <p class="review-content">REVIEW TEXT</p>
    <p class="blockquote-footer">Yelp</p>
  </div>
</section>



And yeah, vertical-align can take numerical values as well.
But be aware, that if the font-size changes this value also has to be adjusted/tweaked around.
Only this line of CSS is needed in this version:
.stars {vertical-align: 2px;}

Here it is in action:


.reviews {
  color: black;
}

.review-name {
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.review-location {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.stars-container {
  vertical-align: center;
}

.review-date {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.review-content {
  font-size: .9rem;
}


/*new code from here*/

.stars {
  vertical-align: 2px;
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<section id="reviews" class="reviews container-md">
  <div class="review-item">
    <p class="review-name">Brian C.</p>
    <p class="review-location">REVIEW LOCATION</p>
    <p class="review-date">
      <span class="stars"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16"
                            fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-star-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path
                                d="M3.612 15.443c-.386.198-.824-.149-.746-.592l.83-4.73L.173 6.765c-.329-.314-.158-.888.283-.95l4.898-.696L7.538.792c.197-.39.73-.39.927 0l2.184 4.327 4.898.696c.441.062.612.636.282.95l-3.522 3.356.83 4.73c.078.443-.36.79-.746.592L8 13.187l-4.389 2.256z" />
                        </svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                            class="bi bi-star-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path
                                d="M3.612 15.443c-.386.198-.824-.149-.746-.592l.83-4.73L.173 6.765c-.329-.314-.158-.888.283-.95l4.898-.696L7.538.792c.197-.39.73-.39.927 0l2.184 4.327 4.898.696c.441.062.612.636.282.95l-3.522 3.356.83 4.73c.078.443-.36.79-.746.592L8 13.187l-4.389 2.256z" />
                        </svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                            class="bi bi-star-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path
                                d="M3.612 15.443c-.386.198-.824-.149-.746-.592l.83-4.73L.173 6.765c-.329-.314-.158-.888.283-.95l4.898-.696L7.538.792c.197-.39.73-.39.927 0l2.184 4.327 4.898.696c.441.062.612.636.282.95l-3.522 3.356.83 4.73c.078.443-.36.79-.746.592L8 13.187l-4.389 2.256z" />
                        </svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                            class="bi bi-star-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path
                                d="M3.612 15.443c-.386.198-.824-.149-.746-.592l.83-4.73L.173 6.765c-.329-.314-.158-.888.283-.95l4.898-.696L7.538.792c.197-.39.73-.39.927 0l2.184 4.327 4.898.696c.441.062.612.636.282.95l-3.522 3.356.83 4.73c.078.443-.36.79-.746.592L8 13.187l-4.389 2.256z" />
                        </svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                            class="bi bi-star-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path
                                d="M3.612 15.443c-.386.198-.824-.149-.746-.592l.83-4.73L.173 6.765c-.329-.314-.158-.888.283-.95l4.898-.696L7.538.792c.197-.39.73-.39.927 0l2.184 4.327 4.898.696c.441.062.612.636.282.95l-3.522 3.356.83 4.73c.078.443-.36.79-.746.592L8 13.187l-4.389 2.256z" />
                        </svg></span> Jul 10, 2019
    </p>
    <p class="review-content">REVIEW TEXT</p>
    <p class="blockquote-footer">Yelp</p>
  </div>
</section>




The result looks good, but the answer is lacking an explanation. What did you change and why does this solve the problem? What does .stars {} do in your stylesheet?

@KIKOSoftware Thank you for pointing these out. I now added a bit of explanation. I also commented the code with /*new code from here*/. The .stars {} has no purpose in the stylesheet, it was a remaining from the OP's stylesheet. I didn't change anything else, I just added in plus to the end.

I've updated my answer. @KIKOSoftware. Many thanks.

I've upvoted your question. This is a good answer to the question asked.
